# Reading excel file from zip archive using python and openpyxl

Tags: python, password-protection, openpyxl

I have a password protected zip archive containing some excel spreadsheets with some confidential data. I'd like to take the password from the user, open the zip, and analyze the spreadsheet inside, without actually extracting the excel file. Is it possible to construct openpyxl's workbook from the zip entry directly and do some analysis on the data in the workbook? I am trying to avoid extracting the excel to file system to avoid potential security problems (e.g. undeleted temp files).

Is this possible to do? Is it possible, for example, to treat the zip archive as some pseudo file system?

Thanks in advance!